# Should question tags that are actually unrelated with the question be removed?

Tags: discussion, tags, editing-help

There are sometimes questions that will be entered to provide the context of a question, but in the end are themselves unrelated with the question or solution. Should they be edited out?

(the question that led me to ask this is [How to run python macros in LibreOffice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413664/how-to-run-python-macros-in-libreoffice) which has little to do with "Ubuntu" )

Comment: Definitely, yes. One common place these unrelated tags get added, too, is IDE-tags, just because they are writing the code in that IDE.

Comment: Actually, the Ubuntu tag seems related for this question as the asker did try to change a file under a specific path that could well be in Ubuntu... So here I wouldn't remove the tags. It would be quite a different question under a Windows or Mac OS.

Comment: [How do I correctly tag my questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions)

Comment: No, in fact add more random tags to questions.  ಠ_ಠ